# RecyclerView did not updating items on OnPostExecute()

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-recyclerview, jsoup

Greetings in advance to all the people here.

I have been wandering between the problem and the madness while I was finding the solution to my problem, I have already invested more of the time possible in solving my dilemma, now I need the most knowledgeable in the subject to help me.

As I detail below, what I'm doing or at least trying to do is updating a `RecyclerView` while I'm collecting certain data that is being saved in the `DB` and in the `list of elements`.

The data that I'm going to paint in the `RecyclerView`, I get it in the following way, with `rssparser` I first get a list of links that later with `Jsoup`, I get images and text of the news.

It happens that these functions that use interaction with the network have to be called inside `threads` that are not those of the UI, and good I believe that I have created there like multithreading, and good the function that does this obtaining of data I could within a asynchronous task.

Another thing I need is for the `progress bubble` in this view to be maintained until the processing of the threads is finished. Ideally it would work in real time, I have done it but it does not work for me by adding each new element to the list and notifying the adapter of a new inserted item.

When the processing of the task ends, and the threads complete their work, I do not update the `RecyclerView` with `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` either, I do not know what else to try, maybe I have some algorithmic error.

Below I'm going to put my code, I apologize for my trail, sure I have left some little unnecessary code or commented.

**The Fragment:**

```
public class ViewerNewsFragment1 extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";

private int mColumnCount = 1;
private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "id";


// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private Integer mParam1;
private String finalUrl;
private ViewerNewsRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeView;
private TextView connectionError;
private int imageHolder;
private NewsHelper newsHelper;



private String SENT_ = "SMS_SENT_SUSCRIPTION_";
private String DELIVERED_ = "SMSDELIVERED_SUSCRIPTION_";
private BroadcastReceiver sendBroadcastReceiver;
private BroadcastReceiver deliveryBroadcastReceiver;

List<News> news = new ArrayList<>();

private boolean flag =  false;
OkHttpClient client;

private boolean isAlreadyRefresh;


public ViewerNewsFragment1() {
}


public static ViewerNewsFragment1 newInstance(int columnCount, Integer id) {
    ViewerNewsFragment1 fragment = new ViewerNewsFragment1();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
    args.putInt(ARG_PARAM1, id);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    newsHelper = new NewsHelper(getActivity());
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
        mParam1 = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM1);
        DummyContent.DummyItem item = DummyContent.ITEMS.get(new Integer(mParam1) - 1);
        finalUrl = item.url;
        imageHolder = item.smallimage;

    }
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_viewer_news_list, container, false);
    // Set the adapter

    Context context = view.getContext();
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_news);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    adapter = new ViewerNewsRecyclerViewAdapter(news, mListener, imageHolder, newsHelper.getNewsDao());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    swipeView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    swipeView.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeView.setProgressViewOffset(false, 0,
            (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 24, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    connectionError = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.connection_error);
    setRetainInstance(true);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.acerca_toolbar);
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f2f2f2"));
    ImageView iv =  (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.iconToShow);
    toolbar.getContext().setTheme(R.style.AppTheme2);
    int img_bar = R.drawable.appbar_cubadebate;
    SharedPreferences preferences = ((ViewerActivity) mListener).getSharedPreferences("client_data", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = preferences.edit();
    if (mParam1.equals(1)) {
        ed.putInt("cubadebate", 0);
        ed.commit();
        img_bar = R.drawable.appbar_cubadebate;
    } else if (mParam1.equals(2)) {
        ed.putInt("granma", 0);
        ed.commit();
        img_bar = R.drawable.appbar_granma;
    } else if (mParam1.equals(3)) {
        ed.putInt("prela", 0);
        ed.commit();
        img_bar = R.drawable.appbar_pl;
    }
    iv.setImageResource(img_bar);
    isAlreadyRefresh = false;
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);


    Dao<News, Integer> dao = newsHelper.getNewsDao();
    try {
        QueryBuilder<News, Integer> builder = newsHelper.getNewsDao().queryBuilder();
        builder.where().eq("author", mParam1.toString());
        builder.limit(20);
        builder.orderBy("newsDate", false); // true for ascending, false for descending
        news = dao.query(builder.prepare());

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    adapter.setmValues(news);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return view;
}


private void fetchNews() {
    fetchInternalNews();
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {

        Cache cache = new Cache(getContext().getCacheDir(), Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                        return originalResponse.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "max-age=" + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365)).build();
                    }
                })
                .cache(cache)
                .build();

        Parser parser = new Parser();
        parser.execute(finalUrl);

        parser.onFinish(new Parser.OnTaskCompleted() {

            @Override
            public void onTaskCompleted(final ArrayList<Article> list) {

                new LongOperation().execute(list);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                if (getActivity() != null)
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            swipeView.setRefreshing(false);
                            connectionError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            isAlreadyRefresh = false;
                     }
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        swipeView.setRefreshing(false);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No tiene conexión a Internet. Active la Wi-Fi o los datos móviles, y vuelva a intentarlo.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<List<Article>, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(List<Article>... lists) {
        swipeView.setRefreshing(true);
        GoScrapp(lists[0]);
        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       isAlreadyRefresh = true;
       swipeView.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}
public void GoScrapp(List<Article> list){

    Dao<News, Integer> dao = newsHelper.getNewsDao();
    News t = new News();
    List<News> news_list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        QueryBuilder<News, Integer> builder = newsHelper.getNewsDao().queryBuilder();
        builder.where().eq("author", mParam1.toString());
        builder.limit(20);
        builder.orderBy("newsDate", false); // true for ascending, false for descending
        news_list = dao.query(builder.prepare());

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    boolean esta = false;
    for (Article article : list) {
        if(!news_list.isEmpty())
            for (News item : news_list) {
                if(item.getLink().equals(article.getLink())){
                    esta = true;
                }
            }else esta = false;

        if(!esta) {
            Foo foo = new Foo(article);
            Thread th = new Thread(foo);
            try {
                th.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

private void fetchInternalNews() {       
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    onRefresh();
    //Todo:Puse este valor en true, estaba en false
    isAlreadyRefresh = true;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    if (!isAlreadyRefresh) {
        swipeView.setRefreshing(true);
        swipeView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fetchNews();
                isAlreadyRefresh = true;
                adapter.setmValues(news);
            }
        }, 1000);
    } else
        swipeView.setRefreshing(false);
}


public interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {

    void onListFragmentInteraction(Integer id);
}

private boolean CanSuscribe(){
    NewsHelper helper = new NewsHelper(getContext());
    SuscriptionRequest sr_object;
    Date today = new Date();
    boolean result;

    try {
        if(!helper.getSuscriptionRequestDao().queryForEq(SuscriptionRequest.FUENTE, mParam1).isEmpty())
        {
            sr_object = helper.getSuscriptionRequestDao().queryForEq(SuscriptionRequest.FUENTE, mParam1).get(0);
            //get the date of usscription
            Date date = sr_object.getFecha();
            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(/* remember about timezone! */);
            calendar.setTime(date);
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 30);
            date = calendar.getTime();
            result = today.after(date);
        } else {
            result = true;
        }
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e("ERROR Saving SR", e.getMessage());
        result =  false;
    }
    return result;
}

private void SaveSuscriptionRequest(){

    NewsHelper helper = new NewsHelper(getContext());
    SuscriptionRequest sr = new SuscriptionRequest();

    try{
        if(!helper.getSuscriptionRequestDao().queryForEq(SuscriptionRequest.FUENTE, mParam1).isEmpty()) {
            sr.setFecha(new Date());
            sr.setFuente(mParam1);
            helper.getSuscriptionRequestDao().create(sr);
        } else {
            sr = helper.getSuscriptionRequestDao().queryForEq(SuscriptionRequest.FUENTE, mParam1).get(0);
            sr.setFecha(new Date());
            helper.getSuscriptionRequestDao().update(sr);
        }


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e("ERROR Saving SR", e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void sendMessage(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    final Activity mContext = (Activity) mListener;
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, new Intent(SENT_), 0);
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED_), 0);
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(flag) {
        myOnDestroy();
    }
}

public class Foo implements Runnable {
    private volatile String value;
    private String url;
    private Article article;




    public Foo(Article article){
        this.url = article.getLink();
        this.article = article;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        OkHttp3Downloader okHttpDownloader = new OkHttp3Downloader(client);
        Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(getContext()).downloader(okHttpDownloader).build();

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements links = new Elements();
            Elements img = new Elements();
            String img_url = "";

            switch (mParam1){
                case 1:
                    links = doc.select("div[class=note_content] > p");
                    img = doc.select("div[id^=\"attachment_\"] > img");
                    if(!img.isEmpty())
                    {
                        img_url = img.first().attr("srcset").split(" ")[0];
                        if(img_url.isEmpty())
                            img_url = img.first().attr("src");
                        if(!img_url.isEmpty()) picasso.with(getContext()).load(img_url).fetch();
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    links = doc.select("div[class=story-body-text story-content] > p");
                    img = doc.select("div[class=image] > img");
                    if(!img.isEmpty()){
                        img_url = "http://www.granma.cu"+img.first().attr("src");
                        Log.e("URL", img_url);
                        if(!img_url.isEmpty()) picasso.with(getContext()).load(img_url).fetch();
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    links = doc.select("div[class=fullNewsFulltext]");
                    img = doc.select("div[class=fullNewsIntrotext] img");
                    if(!img.isEmpty()){
                        img_url = "http://prensa-latina.cu"+img.first().attr("src");
                        Log.e("URL", img_url);
                        if(!img_url.isEmpty()) picasso.with(getContext()).load(img_url).fetch();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            for (Element link : links) {
                builder.append(link.text()).append("\n");
            }
            value = article.getLink();

            Dao<News, Integer> dao = newsHelper.getNewsDao();
            News t = new News();
            String author = "";
            t.setTitle(article.getTitle());
            t.setAuthor(mParam1.toString());
            t.setDescription(article.getDescription());
            t.setLink(article.getLink());
            t.setCompleteDescription(builder.toString());
            t.setImage(article.getImage());
            t.setImage_link(img_url);





            if (article.getPubDate() != null)
                t.setNewsDate(article.getPubDate());
            else {
                final SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
                try {
                    t.setNewsDate(sf.parse(sf.format(new Date())));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR FECHA", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            try {
                List<News> existing = dao.queryForEq("title", t.getTitle());
                if (existing.size() == 0) {
                    dao.create(t);
                    news.add(t);
                    Log.e("ERROR FECHA", "ADD"+t.getTitle());

                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // Stuff that updates the UI
                            adapter.notifyItemInserted(news.size() - 1);


//             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   //                                swipeView.setRefreshing(true);
                        }
                    });


//                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            builder.append("Error : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
        }
    }


    public String getValue() {
        return value;

    }
}

public void myOnDestroy(){
    final Activity mContext = (Activity) mListener;
    mContext.unregisterReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver);
    mContext.unregisterReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReceiver);
}

}
```

Comment: You are not updating any data in `onPostExecute()` why you are calling `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` ?

Comment: This did not solve my problem the list is not updated correctly or it is not list the elements, it remains empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides adityakamble49's answer. The problem might be located here inside GoScrapp function:

```
 if(!esta) {
        Foo foo = new Foo(article);
        Thread th = new Thread(foo);
        try {
            th.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

you are starting a new thread inside doInBackground() that process the data and updates the DB, so onPostExecute() is executed before the thread inserts the data to the DB.

Comment: A thousand thanks to the partner @Isidro Rodriguez who helped me find the solution and saved me from so much pain. Finally it was a problem with the threads, unnecessary threads that I had added in my code. I'm alive thanks IsidroRodriguez.

Answer (score 1):

You are **not** **updating** any adapter **data** in `onPostExecute()` method and calling notifyDatasetChanged

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   isAlreadyRefresh = true;
   swipeView.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

You need to call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` **only** when you update adapter data.

I see you have updated your adapter data in `onRefresh()` method but you haven't called `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`. So you need to add **notifyDatasetChanged** as shown in code below.

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    if (!isAlreadyRefresh) {
        swipeView.setRefreshing(true);
        swipeView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fetchNews();
                isAlreadyRefresh = true;
                adapter.setmValues(news);
                adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() // <- Add this
            }
        }, 1000);
    } else
        swipeView.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

This could be one of the reason your `RecyclerView` is not updated

Comment: You are right in your comment and in your answer but, this did not solve my problem the list is not updated correctly or it is not list the elements, it remains empty.

Comment: Have you tried adding `notifyDatasetChanged` in `onRefresh` ?

Comment: Look, this sentence ,'adapter.setmValues(news);' in the adapter call notifyDatasetChanged and alredy is there. But anyway, I tried and did not update, my list goes blank, it seems like a lot of work and the UI ends before tasks from the background.